# Matching multiple python regexes in a line in tarfile opened tar file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pcre

Please how do I overcome the problem of

```
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

when trying to run multiple regexes match against a line from the file?
The multiple match I am trying is:

```
re.match('|'.join('(?:{0})'.format(x) for x in (regex1, regex2, regex3)), line):
```

which works in plain text file matches and which I attribute to StackOverflow assistance.

I have compiled the regexes like so:

```
regex1 = re.compile(b'http\:\/\/ipaddress\:port\/service\?')
regex2 = re.compile(b'\_event\=new?')
regex3 = re.compile(b'askment\:')
```

but this TypeError still appears.

Earlier in my script I can get away with this:
    match = re.search(b'something-string:\s+111+\d{2,5}', line)
So I thought prefixing the regexes with 'b' in the multiple match was sufficient.
Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `r' ... ' ` instead of `b' ... '`

Comment: I cant use r'..' because its not a plain text file being read.

Answer (score 1):

I had to decode the line, since its coming in as a binary stream.

```
re.match('|'.join('(?:{0})'.format(x) for x in (regex1, regex2, regex3)), line.decode("ascii or something else")):
```